#  Right click on Chrome, Eclipse, etc.. triggered double click instead of single click

Tags: mouse, menu

in my current ubuntu 10.10, every time I right click on a link in chrome, the first option in right-click-menu is selected immediately instead of letting my choosing. The same thing happened in my Indigo eclipse.

I'm using ubuntu 10.10 on pc with AMD graphics card

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug, see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/365300?comments=all

You can see from the discussion there that this problem doesn't affect certain models of mouses.